# Pandas Finding cross sell in two columns in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

What I'm trying to do is a kind of a cross sell.

I have a Pandas dataframe with two columns, one with receipt numbers, and the other with product ids:

```py
receipt  product
1        a
1        b
2        c
3        b
3        a
```

Most of the receipts have many products. What I need to find is the count of combinations of products that happen in the receipts. Let's say products 'a' and 'b' are the most common combination (they appear together in most of the receipts), how do I find this information?

I tried using `df.groupby(['receipt','product']).count()` but this only brings me the count of combinations for receipt + product, not the count of relation of products per receipt.

Any help is aprecciated, and thanks!

Comment: can you show an expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do a cross merge:

```
new_df = df.merge(df, on='receipt')
(new_df[new_df['product_x'] < new_df['product_y']]
     .groupby(['product_x','product_y'])['receipt'].count()
)
```

Output:

```
product_x  product_y
a          b            2
Name: receipt, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you looking for

`df.groupby(['receipt']).agg({'product': list}).assign(count=lambda x: x['product'].str.len())`

```
        product  count
receipt
1        [a, b]      2
2           [c]      1
3        [b, a]      2
```

Comment: This actually brings the possible combinations for each receipt. What I wanted to find was if the combinations in a receipt appear in other receipts, and their count. For instance, if 'a' and 'b' also appear in another receipt. Is that even possible?

Comment: I am going to need an example of what your looking for, I'm not sure I fully understand

Comment: Sorry, I'll try my best: I have a column with receipt IDs, and another column with product IDs. For instance: I buy soda and chips (this generates a receipt), and another person buys soda and cookies (another receipt, with another ID). What I want to find is the count of combinations, so, how many times does soda + chips appears in the receipts? And soda + cookies? etc. In the example above, I have a receipt with two products, and the same products appears in another receipt.